# How to remove empty option from select Drupal 8 forms

Tags: 8, forms

How to remove empty option from the select list in drupal forms.

```
$form['property'] = [
    '#type'          => 'select',
    '#id'            => 'property',
    '#attributes'    => ['class' => ['form-control']],
    '#title'         => $this->t('Hotel'),
    '#options'       => $properties,
    '#empty_option'  => t('Select Category'),
    '#required'      => TRUE,
    '#validated' => True,
];
```

I have removed the line `'#empty_option'  => t('Select Category')` from the code but in the front end it shows blank for the first option. I need to select the first element of the `$properties` array to be selected as default.

Comment: set a default value `#default_value`?

Comment: @4k4 setting `'#default_value' => false` and removing `'#empty_option'  => t('Select Category'),` was the trick. thanks !!